# Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$username when using PDO to login

Tags: php, pdo, stdclass

I am creating a fairly basic login form using PDO for the first time. I'm pretty new to PDO and can't figure this one out.

My code is:

```
require_once('setEnv.php');
require_once( 'functions/functions.php' );

$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];

$db = classes_pdoDB::getConnection();
$query = "SELECT password, salt
    FROM user
    WHERE username=:username";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username));

while($asd = $stmt->fetchObject()){

echo $asd->username;

}
```

and the error message I am getting is

```
  Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$username in /var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_v010224/public_html/project/executeLog.php on line 18
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $query = "SELECT password, salt
> ```

You are not selecting the `username`, so the result doesn't have one.

Comment: Oh this is the exact reason I used to use SELECT *, thanks for pointing out my idiocy.

Comment: Select fields which you need. Select * is generally considered bad approach. Be disciplined on codeing. It'l save you much headache.